# variable current value doesn't change when i call the "showPrevious" function

Tags: javascript, html

This program was meant to change the src property of an image element 
     via an array

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
 <title>Url next, previous</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">


 var imagesarr = ["Eikona1.jpg","Eikona2.jpg","Eikona3.jpg"];
 var current = 0;


 function showNext() {
     current ++;    

     if(current==imagesarr.length) {
        current = 0;
     }
     document.getElementById("img").src = imagesarr[current];   
   }
```

here is the problem! It gets value: 1 
instead of -1. Current price doesnt work...by calling `showPrevious()` function the current value should change to -1 insted of 1.

```
  function showPrevious() {

    current = current - 1 ;  

     if(current < 0) {
        current = imagesarr.length - 1;
     }
     document.getElementById("img").scr = imagesarr[current];   
  }

 </script>


 </head>

 <body>

 <img src="Eikona1.jpg" id="img" alt="Einstein" style="width:600px; 
 height:500px"/>
 <br/>
```

On click events will trigger each function

```
 <input id="previous" type="button" value="Previous" style="width:220px; 
 margin-top:40px" onclick="showPrevious()"/>

 <input id="next" type="button" value="Next" style="width:220px; margin- 
 top:40px" onclick="showNext()"/> 

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `scr` should be `src`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: FYI, you can use `current--` instead of `current = current - 1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "current price doesn't work"?

Comment: Why should the value change to `-1`? The check `if (current < 0)` prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

You had one typo, src was scr but moreover there was the issue with logic. Perhaps this revised one will clear it up a bit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var imagesarr = ["1","2","3"];
var current = 0;

function showNext() {
    current ++;

    if(current==imagesarr.length) {
       current = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("img").src = imagesarr[current];
  }

 function showPrevious() {
   current --;

   if(current < 0) {
      current = imagesarr.length-1;
   }
   document.getElementById("img").src = imagesarr[current];
 }

</script>
```